# what is the big difference between @Injecg and by ViewModel in Android ViewModel?

Tags: android

I often use @Inject ViewModel or by viewModels() at developing.
In some cases @Inject works or not, then I use by viewModels() instead.
I learned by viewModels() is cached in lifeCycle so return same viewModel, and @Inject always create new ViewModel if there is no @Singleton.
Is what I understand right?

```
    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModel: BookMarkImageViewModel


    val viewModel: BookMarkImageViewModel by viewModels()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is `by viewmodel` will hook to register the instance to your Lifecycle. The `@inject` will only generate a new instance, just like you would with `BookMarkImageViewModel()`

According to Google and Android it is best practise to use the `by viewModels()`.